# Any example or scenario where Angular router Params Observable is usable?

Tags: angular

I was learning on Angular Router Params Observable in Pluralsight course(Routing).

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {let id = params['id']})});
```

I understand within component, when there is change in params, we use above code.

I would like to know an example, or scenario this plays role in real time application?

Comment: Navigating from same `child.route` to similar `child.route` with different parameters

Comment: `server/user/show/1` to `server/user/show/2` to display user details

Answer (score 0):

I use that in my application like this:

Inside component :

```
const userId$ = this.route.params.map(params=> params['userId']);
userService.getUser(userId$)
   .subscribe(users => this.users = users);
```

User Service

```
getUser(userId$){
   return userId$.flatMap(userId => this.http.get(url+'/'+userId);
}
```

In the above scenario I have declared a relation between routes and userservice . So, when a user clicks on a different user , the url changes and automatically a new http request is sent and the data in UI is updated. 
So basically I am saying, observe the route params and if 'userId' value changes do http call and update UI .

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are building a social networking site and on one page you list all your friends and the user can open the profile page of the friend by clicking on his name.

Now to build your listing page you would display all your friends in a `*ngFor` loop like below :

```
<div *ngFor="let friend of friends">
    <a routerLink="/detailPage">
      <img [src]="friend.profilePic" />
      <span>{{friend.name}}</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

When we navigate to the `detailPage` how would you know to show the details of which friend ?

There are a few ways of doing this:

1. Store the `userId` of friend in a service
2. Store it in localStorage
3. Pass it as route param in the URl

Let's take an example, suppose you click on the name of your friend **Batman**

First Approach:

You can easily do this by creating a shared service between two component, the `ListComponent` which displays the list of friends and `DetailComponent` which shows a particular friend's details.

The problem with this approach is when you refresh your page you will not have the `userId` as the javascript scope is destroyed by the browser and you cannot share it any other friend who might wanna see the profile of your friend. Let's say you have a friend called **catwoman** who asks you to give link to Batman's account, oops you can't because you don't know it !!

Second Approach:

Here you will know what is the `userId` on page refresh but the problem of not sharing someone's link still exists which defeats the purpose of a social network.

Third Approach:

This is the best approach in this scenario as you will have the `userId` on refresh and you can send the link of Batman's profile to catwoman :)

So you change `routerLink="/detailPage"` to `routerLink="/detailPage/{{friend.userId}}"`.